# Using Raw SQL with Doctrine

Tags: sql, symfony1, doctrine

I have some extremely complex queries that I need to use to generate a report in my application. I'm using symfony as my framework and doctrine as my ORM.

My question is this:

What is the best way to pass in highly-complex sql queries directly to Doctrine without converting them to the Doctrine Query Language? I've been reading about the `Raw_SQL` extension but it appears that you still need to pass the query in sections (like `from()`). Is there anything for just dumping in a bunch of raw sql commands?

Comment: Excuse me the off-topic but what tool/library are you using to generate your application reports?

Best regards!

Comment: Right now? Just SQL, raw PHP, and gall. :D

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
$q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$result = $q->execute(" -- RAW SQL HERE -- ");
```

See the Doctrine API documentation for different execution methods.

Comment: @simple: Yes, you can use any SQL you want.

Comment: As this answer seems to be popular, I should add that this method bypasses the escaping offered by Doctrine, so escape stuff manually or you may leave yourself open to SQL injection holes.

Comment: It looks to me that this answer is for Doctrine version < 2. For raw queries in Doctrine 2, I found this post helpful: http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=37872

Comment: I found that adding ->getDbh() as in @richsage's answer prevents warnings from happening when the doctrine profiler is enabled.

Answer (score 41):

Yes. You can get a database handle from Doctrine using the following code:

```
$pdo = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
```

and then execute your SQL as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE param1 = :param1 AND param2 = :param2";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);

$params = array(
  "param1"  => "value1",
  "param2"  => "value2"
);
$stmt->execute($params);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

You can use bound variables as in the above example.

Note that Doctrine won't automatically hydrate your results nicely into record objects etc, so you'll need to deal with the results being returned as an array, consisting of one array per row returned (key-value as column-value).

Comment: Is there a way to force doctrine to hydrate the results I get via the PDO? or do I just have to work with what I'm given?

Comment: From memory when I used the above, not automatically as Doctrine doesn't know what columns you have.  If you named the columns well enough, I guess you could use fromArray() or similar, but the data would need to be re-formatted into something usable for that.

Comment: If you can, use your query to return a record ID and then use plain old $table->find($id) to load it.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what do you mean saying *raw SQL*, but you coud execute traditional SQL queries this way:

```
... 
// $this->_displayPortabilityWarning();

$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
$pdo = $conn->execute($sql);
$pdo->setFetchMode(Doctrine_Core::FETCH_ASSOC);
$result = $pdo->fetchAll();
...
```

The following method is not necsessary, but it shows a good practice.

```
protected function _displayPortabilityWarning($engine = 'pgsql')
{
     $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection();
     $driver = $conn->getDriverName();

     if (strtolower($engine) != strtolower($driver)) {
        trigger_error('Here we have possible database portability issue. This code was tested on ' . $engine . ' but you are trying to run it on ' . $driver, E_USER_NOTICE);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use Doctrine_RawSql(); to create raw SQL queries which will hydrate to doctrine objects.

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted, that Doctrine2 uses PDO as a base, thus I would recommend using prepared statements over plain old execute.

Example:

```
$db = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `someField` FROM `someTable` WHERE `field` = :value");
$query->execute(array('value' => 'someValue'));
```

Comment: This question is about Symfony 1. On Symfony 1, Doctrine 1.2 is used - This answer might be misguiding.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to mislead. The solution is still valid though as Symfony 1 can be used with Doctrine as well.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony insert raw sql using doctrine.

This in version Symfoney 1.3

```
$q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$result = $q->execute($query);
```