# INSERT INTO table_a SELECT * from table_b with doctrine2

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Does doctrine 2 support some kind of 
"select into"-syntax?

In pure MySQL it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
  FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

I checked the manual, yet without sucess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am refering to Doctrine in version 2.3.1:
In this version you can get the current connection to the database from ORM/EntityManager.
There is only one connection (this was different in Doctrine 1).
Here is what worked for me for the insert-select-task:

```
$db = $this->_em->getConnection();
$query = "INSERT INTO table2 (myfield) SELECT table1.myfield FROM table1 WHERE table1.id < 1000";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$params = array();
$stmt->execute($params);
```

There is also an interesting answer here: [Using Raw SQL with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774947/using-raw-sql-with-doctrine) with an code example how to check "raw sql" for PDO compatiblity.

Comment: i have the same problem and my query was without this prepare() property. but when i add it it gave me this error FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Query::prepare() in controller