# Symfony2 - CreateBuilder - Query in other Query

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

How can we execute this query with doctrine in Symfony 2:

SQL:

```
SELECT p.* FROM messages, (SELECT * from posts ORDER BY created_at DESC) as p GROUP BY p.category_id ORDER BY message.created_at;
```

Probleme: Every table must be an Entity like MyProjectMyBundle:MyEntity, **(SELECT * from posts ORDER BY created_at DESC)** is not an Entity...

Symfony 2 (doesnt work):

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT p.* 
              FROM MyProjectMyBundle:Messages, 
              (SELECT * from posts ORDER BY created_at DESC) as p 
              GROUP BY p.category_id ORDER BY message.createdAt');
```

Can we include an other query like Mysql? A solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Doctrine does not allow you to make subqueries inside the From statement. However, you can type regular sql into doctrine.

Here is a post on this: [Using Raw SQL with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774947/using-raw-sql-with-doctrine)

Comment: Thanks. A good way to keep Entities with a native SQL Query: http://sf2.memosdedev.com/creer-une-requete-sql-native-dans-symfony2-avec-doctrine2.html